# Use a specific index from a table while running a query with multiple joins

Tags: postgresql, join, indexing

I have multiple indexes on a postgres table -

- On primary id (notification_permission_on_user_id)
- On three different columns (notification_channel_route_type)

I'm running a query with two joins and the second one caters to my requirement better. But when I analyze the query, it uses primary_id_index automatically, which I assume is decided by postgres itself based on the query.

```
Index Scan using notification_permission_on_user_id on notification_permission  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=21) (never executed)
           Index Cond: (user_id = u.id)
           Filter: ((channel = 1) AND (type = 2))
```

How do I make sure that my query uses the second index which suits my need and would really speed up the process?

Comment: Why do you think the 2nd index suits your needs better?  It is hard to be more selective than a primary key.  Also, an index on `(channel, route, type)` is not all that well suited to a query that specifies "type" but not "route".

Comment: Actually in my query, I am using all three of the params: (channel, route, type), and with every query I need the results with a specific value of them.
Hence I figure I should be using the second index because that'll filter my data based on my exact requirement and take lesser time as I'll be doing this for a larger set of data.

Comment: But your plan fragment doesn't show "route" being used in the filter.  Is it applied somewhere else in the plan instead?

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition so that the index cannot be used:

```
... WHERE/ON notification_permission.user_id + 0 = u.id
```